# Select returns weird result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: tables]

I want to show 10 columns (blue arrow in the picture) from 7 related tables, but my query returns weird result.

I have tried using subqueries, change the join orders, nothing works.

```
Select distinct 
    c.id_penjualan,
    d.nama_transaksi_pengeluaran, e.nama_pelanggan,
    f.no_kombinasi, g.nama_produk, c.harga, c.jumlah,
    c.subtotal, c.no_voucher, c.no_polisi 
from 
    t.penjualan_h a 
inner join 
    spbu142071163.t.penjualan_d b on a.no_penjualan = b.no_penjualan 
inner join 
    spbu142071163.t.penjualan_d2 c on b.no_penjualan = c.no_penjualan 
inner join 
    spbu142071163.m.tipe_transaksi_pengeluaran d on b.kode_tipe_transaksi_pengeluaran = d.kode_tipe_transaksi_pengeluaran 
inner join  
    m.pelanggan e on b.kode_pelanggan = e.kode_pelanggan 
inner join 
    m.kombinasi f on c.no_kombinasi = f.no_kombinasi 
inner join 
    m.produk g on f.kode_produk = g.kode_produk 
where 
    a.no_penjualan = 'PNJLN190717.001' 
    and a.no_penjualan = c.no_penjualan 
    and c.kode_pelanggan = e.kode_pelanggan
```

[image: result]

The result isn’t what I expected, the right result should be only row 1 & 4. I don’t know where row 2 & 3 came from and want to get rid of them.

Comment: What determines whether you want "CASH" or "EDC" (or other) as the type? You are storing multiple types of transactions in your tables (tipe_transaki_pengeluarna sounds an awful lot like transaction type) so you will need to filter out. But since you have expected rows 1 & 4 it makes the requirements unclear to me.

Comment: Something is wrong with one of the joins. Based on your schema and query it looks like the problem is related to `inner join 
    spbu142071163.m.tipe_transaksi_pengeluaran d on b.kode_tipe_transaksi_pengeluaran = d.kode_tipe_transaksi_pengeluaran 
`

Comment: @CaitLANJenner My database name is spbu142071163, so it actually doesn't matter. I deleted the others to avoid confusion, but I missed these :)

Comment: @JacobH You are right, tipe_transaksi_pengeluaran means Transaction Type. I have Cash, EDC (Using EDC Machine - Debit/Credit Card), Prepaid, Postpaid, Tera (this one is for calibrating the petrol, seldom use it). Meanwhile, pelanggan table means Customer. I have several customers on the list, Cash, being one of them, is used for both Cash and EDC (Cash customer is everyone who pays in cash or using EDC machine).

Comment: So since you have multiple transaction types in your tables, you get multiple rows in your result unless you filter them out or add additional join criteria so that you have a 1:1 join instead of 1:N. You will note that your "nama_pelanggan" is "Cash" for row 4. But should be "EDC". Here is the crux of your problem.